# Call jupyter notebooks from other jupyter notebook in parallel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, parallel-processing

I have a cell in my main jupyter notebook which runs other secondary notebooks.

```
%run ./Notebook1.ipynb
%run ./Notebook2.ipynb
%run ./Notebook3.ipynb
%run ./Notebook4.ipynb
%run ./Notebook5.ipynb
```

However, this way I run them sequentially. Is there any way I could achieve the same thing but running the notebooks in parallel?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help, but why would you need to call a notebook from another?

Comment: it depends on what these notebooks do, and what do you get from them, like do they setup some variables ? or just save things to disk ? also do they really need to be jupyter notebooks ? you seem like you are using .ipynb files as an alternative to .py files, which is setting the limitations.

Comment: @AhmedAEK They provision some data into DB tables, so I don't need any output from them.

Comment: converting them to .py files and running them in a python subprocess should achieve what you need, there are complex tricks to do it with multiprocessing instead of subprocess but it's usually unnecessary, you might also just run multiple versions of jupyter in subprocesses, but that is just a waste of resources.